# How can I read the multinominal naive bayers in simple english?

Tags: data-analysis, symbolic-computation, naive-bayes

I trying to studying about text classifier but I have some problems to understand the math representations of scikit.learn implementation:

[image]

How can I describe this using simple english?

Answer (score 0):

This use of the same notation, in this case the capital $P,$ to represent different functions, is obnoxious but is widespread among engineers, physicists and the like.

What is happening is that first you're finding the conditional probability distribution of one uncertain quantity given the observed values of several others, and then you're finding the most probable value of that one random variable, given those others.